# How do two different components communicate with one another?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I am using the Provider injectors to send a command from the Signin component  to the Profile component to sign out.  Although, the console logs shows me that the Signout function has worked as expected, the (HTML) *ngIf directives doesn't change accordingly.

What am I doing wrong?

```
**Signin component**

import {Component, OnInit,  Injectable  } from '@angular/core';

import {ProfileUserComponent} from '../profile.user.component/profile.user.component'


@Component({
  selector: 'signin-button',
  template: `<button (click)="onSignOut()"  *ngIf="loggedIn === true "  >Sign Out</button> 
<button  (click)="onSignIn()"  *ngIf="loggedIn !== true "  >Sign In</button> 
`,
  providers: [ProfileUserComponent]


})




@Injectable()
export class SigninComponent { 

loggedIn: boolean;

constructor(public http: Http, private profileUserComponent: ProfileUserComponent ){}

      ngOnInit(): any{}

onSignOut(): void{

// send command to the profile component
this.profileUserComponent.signout(false);     

}

}





 **ProfileUserComponent**
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable} from '@angular/core';



    @Component({
            selector:'profile-user',
            template: `<img class="ui mini image" src="image1.jpg" *ngIf="loggedIn === true">

    <img class="ui mini image" src="image2.jpg" *ngIf="loggedIn === false">

    `,

    })

      signout(status){
        this.loggedIn = status;
        console.log ("logged out", this.loggedIn);  // Console log tells me that "Logged Out False"
}     


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code needs to be re-written. You're trying to inject one component into another, which is wrong. You inject services into components.

If both ProfileUserComponent and SigninComponent have to be components with UI, then you can create a common service that knows login status and is injected into both components. One component can set the login status on the service's property (e.g. isSignedIn: EventEmitter), which will send an event about the login status,  and the other component will listen to this event.

On the side note: @Injectable annotation is not used with components.

Comment: Hi Yakov,  If I understood you correctly, the right way to build the *ProfileUserComponent  is to make  that component listen for changes?                           This is different because because now in Angular2  we use the Rxjs library?

Comment: If there are two sibling components shown at the same time, then introduce a service and have the firs component modify the service, which fire an event on each such modification. If this service is injected into the second component, it can subscribe to those events: myCommonService.varOfTypeEventEmitter.subscribe().

The other scenario is by using a router. If the second component is displayed in the router outlet, it can subscribe to updates from the first component by subscribing to the params property of the ActivatedRoute (it has to be injected in the second component).